# Creating a sticky layout with css

Tags: html, css, layout, sticky

How would I set the page to work [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T5GF.png)?
Each div would then have children inside that should all inherit the behavior.

Basically 3 sections:
Top (green) one is fixed on top as you scroll down, but only until it collides with the third (blue) page section.

If I add `position: sticky;` it doesn't seem to do anything. Or when it does (can't figure out what exactly makes it work), it only affects the section container and not the children inside.
`Position: fixed;` works, but doesn't do what I need.

CODE:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
}

.green {
    background: #5fc466b7;
}

.orange {
    background: #e3c046b7;
}

.blue {
    background: #767bd7b7;
}

p {
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
<div class="orange">
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
<div class="blue">
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to put a container around the first 2 sections, so that the green section stays sticky within that container only. The blue section starts right after this container, so once you scroll beyond the container, the green section will start going up as well. There's a nice explanation [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-position-sticky)

Comment: you need to set the top of the sticky element else it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have added `position:sticky`. You also need to set the `top` css property in order to stack it properly.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
    height:50vh;
}

.green {
    background: #5fc466b7;
}

.orange {
    background: #e3c046b7;
}

.blue {
    background: #767bd7b7;
}

p {
    //padding-bottom: 200px;
}
.sticky{
position: sticky;
top:0;
}
.sticky--last{
top: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="green sticky">
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
<div class="orange">
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
<div class="blue sticky sticky--last">
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How would this work if height of two containers combined is bigger than 100vh, like if there is a lot of content inside? If I add content that expands the containers (so both orange and blue container do not fit on the page fully at the same time), the green section goes over both orange and blue section. I would like it to only go over the orange section and "collide" with blue section. I hope this makes sense.